# How can I encrypt my external SD card on Android?

Tags: security, external-sd, encryption

I want to encrypt or password protect on my external sdcdard.

Thus whenever I remove my ex SD card it will not allow to show any of its data without password, even if it is inserted in Computer.

Is it possible or not? If yes then how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [BoxCryptor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boxcryptor.android). It has companion applications for Windows, Mac, iPhone & iOS. You can keep your encrypted files in cloud (Dropbox, Google Drive or Microsoft SkyDrive) & access them on any platform.

I use it on regular basis for offline files too (what you are looking for). I keep encrypted container of BoxCryptor in my Dropbox and use FolderSync two-way sync to take all files offline on SD Card. Then, I use BoxCryptor to decrypt those files locally whenever I want.

If you don't want to use cloud, just don't use it. Choose SD card in BoxCryptor app. After inserting the SD card to PC or Mac, one needs BoxCryptor applications of Windows, Mac (Encrypted files are compatible with `EncFS-Linux` too) & password to read those files & folders (file names & folder names are also encrypted).

Comment: Does it mount the drive?